# How to type the right ceiling character “⌉” in a windows 7 login password box with a qwerty laptop keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

Dumbest question ever: how can I type with laptop keyboard the "right ceiling" character (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2309/index.htm) aka "⌉" ) in the windows login password box ( http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm ) with a qwerty laptop keyboard?

"Alt +2309" does not give any consistent result, I managed to have Indian characters, squares but never the one I was looking for... (ok just once a few secs ago in google chrome address bar... ⌉)

Comment: Why does http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm not work for you? I guess the laptop has a num lock function? (Like exposing it on the uio, jkl,m,. keys or the like.)

Comment: You are not logged into the system yet, right? You don't say that explicitly, but now I would assume so (I assumed you are using a virtual system or a remote login in my answer below since you/s.o. needed to put in the password as well). Are you specifically looking for the solution to type it in, or is you actual goal to log on (and after that you would change the password or s.th. similar).

Comment: @Albin not, I am not. I am more specifically looking for a way to type it and then change the whole passord it order to have more "regular" characters.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret may I suggest then that you rephrase you're question towards the actual goal: you want to change the password to a password without that special character. This makes many more answers possible (if there are any).

Comment: @Albin no, I am seriously just looking for a way to type this character. About your other question: "Alt +2309", it does not give any consistent result, I managed to have indian characters, squares but never the one I was looking for... (ok just once a few secs ago in google chrome address bar... ⌉) guess it depends on the fonts actually supporting this character

Comment: Just to be sure, you're actually also typing the "+" character for "Alt +2309", right?

Comment: @Arjan yup I did that, see my answer. For some reasons sometimes the character does not show up at all with certain fonts (not even a big uglish square).

Comment: Why not to address this question to your admin who set such "nice" password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>8969 (**important:** type in the number on the numpad, while holding down the "Alt"-key).

**Long answer (and limitations to the solution):** In my test this works with the Win7 password logon input field at the logon prompt (but of course you won't see the character in the password field). I created an account with a password including that character (by copy&paste) and then logged on using the new account successfully (entering the character with my solution). It's possible to replace the native logon prompt, for example with third party software, in this case my solution might not work (if the new logon prompt can not handle Unicode characters). What I haven't tested yet is if the solution works for different a different system code pages.

If you want to "see" that it works you can do it, for example, in Win7 MS Wordpad (use e.g. Cambria Math as font). Wordpad will accept this input method as well as display the character character correctly.

It does not work, for example:

- if you use this input method with MS notepad. Notepad will process the character by using copy and past (although it shows a different character, the binary code representing the character is correct) but not process it correctly with the input method (it creates a different character on a binary level)
- if you use it in text file that uses the ANSI format (instead of Unicode)

This type of character is usually not used for a password that has been created automatic. Usually only characters are used that can be typed by a regular keyboard are used. So I would also make sure that it's not a different character for example a funny looking "7" (seven).

If you ultimate goal is to change the password and you don't insist changing the password by typing in the current password first (which leads you to your problem), I would consider to use a workaround. For example if you have a different account (with the right to change passwords for other users) just log on with this account and change the password.

Just to "finish" the question: according to Ehouarn the final solution was to ask an admin to change the accounts password (who of course has an account with the right to changes the password your account).

Furthermore, this solutions did not work for Windows 10 as this [Test by Ben N](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13208/how-to-improve-this-answer/13209?noredirect=1#comment36741_13209) shows: in the Windows 10 password prompt (which has a button to show the password as typed so far), you get ○, U+25CB WHITE CIRCLE.

Comment: Still not sure how this answers the question, but I guess that's life.

Comment: @BloodPhilia I suggested to double check his assumption, by doing that Ehouarn found out that "his admin" was able to assign a new password, so thats what he did. And I also provided a solution how to put the character into the logon prompt, that worked for me, you are welcome to try it.

Answer (score 1):

At the logon prompt, without any ability to run additional software, the simple answer is that you cannot. There is no alt code available for this unicode character.

The only solution that I would be able to think of is to setup a Rubber Ducky (USB device that types out characters as if it were an input device) to type it. Although I am not sure that that would work as that also only has "keyboard inputs" to work with.

Comment: What about a non-laptop keyboard?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret Same answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Awesome... I should thank the admin who setup that password for me...

Comment: maybe a remote access from another session can do

Comment: @EhouarnPerret However, are you sure it's not the "box drawings light down and left" character (┐)?  That's ALT + 191.

Comment: @From what I've seen it's much longer (vertically) than other kind of character =/

Comment: I found a way to make it work and tested it successfully (see my answer). Verification/Falsification by other users is welcome.